# Which is more appropriate: thin or slim?

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering when should **thin** be used and when should **slim** be used to express lacking weight:

> My friends say that I am too **thin**.
>   My friends say that I am too **slim**.

If they are different, what would be examples of better usage?

Comment: "Too slim" is a more positive word, IMHO. If I wanted to say that the friends are concerned with my low weight, I'd go for **thin**.

Comment: If you have little flesh on the body that make you look rather unattractive, people may call you thin.  If you  have a little flesh on the body wished for an attractive figure, people will call you slim.  In other words, thin has a negative meaning, whereas slim has a positive meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*thin* and *slim* may mean the same thing but they are not *synonyms*. 'Slim' *largely* means being in a good shape not with big muscles or fats. The body is not broad or bulky. Actually a slim person is *thin* ***but*** attractive.

On the other hand, 'thin' refers to a person who looks thinner than she should be to look attractive. *slim* is more positive than *thin*. 'Slim' could be appreciating someone.

If your friends say that you are 'thin', they probably care for you and want you to put on *some* weight.

These days, looking 'slim' is on the rage. So, if you meet a celebrity, calling her 'slim' pleases her; calling her 'thin' may make her face frown!

I'll suggest *not* to use 'too'. Instead, simply say ...

> You look 'thin'

In case of 'too thin', say...

> You look 'very thin'

---

There's one more word - [skinny;](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/skinny_1?q=skinny) but use it with caution!

Comment: You forgot scraggly, anorexic, dystrophic, scrawny, etc. Anyway, your answer is wrong and extremely confusing.

Comment: You are taking it *medically!* You should post an answer to avoid *confusion* from this answer. @Ricky

Comment: Maulik,  Not with big muscles. What an idea!